# Adding an observer to an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, observer-pattern, iphone-sdk-3.1.3, nsnotificationcenter

In my application delegate I have an NSString which can be modified by a class. What I want to do is to have another class observe this NSString and to react whenever this NSString is changed.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the "other class" you must do something like:

```
[MyAppDelegate addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"VARIABLE_NAME" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

and implement

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context;
```